# How to scrape geographic coordinates from dynamic map?

Tags: python, html, google-maps, web-scraping

A dynamic Google map is embedded on a web page, with a drag-gable marker. This gives the location when the marker is dropped. I am trying to scrape the latitude and longitude using python. I have tried the following code:

```
import urllib
import re
url = urllib.urlopen("file:///C:/Users/Test.html").read()

i = 0

regex = '<p>Current Position: Latitude: (.+?) Longitude: (.+?)</p>'
pattern = re.compile(regex)

results = re.findall(pattern,url)

print results
```

This brings up the HTML for the latitude and longitude. How do you retrieve the actual lat/long?

Comment: Don't use regex to parse html, what does the html look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to get the groups  (captured with '(..)' in your regex) from your result:

```
lat = results.groups(1)
long = results.groups(2)
```